# Converting an Excel workbook into multiple worksheet files

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've been trying to find a tutorial on how to convert an [Excel workbook](https://www.lifewire.com/worksheet-and-workbook-3124111) into multiple worksheet files.  I have about 200 rows of data that I need turned into separate files given the value of one of the columns.  How can I do that? The tutorials I have found show me how to separate into worksheets, but not files.

Answer (score 3):

Two methods are available:

1) is explained in https://support.office.com/en-us/article/save-a-worksheet-34b46819-ee08-43d3-bda6-d3abc6346cd9

- Right-click the worksheet name tab.
- Click select *Move or Copy*.
- Click on the drop-down menu *Move selected sheets to Book* & pick *(new book)*.
- Click OK; the new workbook opens with just your moved worksheet.
- Do File | save As and write the new single-worksheet file.

2) After you have a worksheet which does what you want, do *File | Export* and export it to *Tab Separated Value* or *Comma Separated Value*, instead of doing *File | Save As* .  That will discard formatting and formulas, but the data will be intact.